# Mongoose.create creating document but none of my data

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm learning to use the mean stack and trying to build a url shortener. I've got a module that takes the req.params.UserUrl checks and makes sure it's a valid url then creates a random number that I want to use as the short route. I can't seem to find a way to save the random number so that I can check their next url request against it. After a google search it seemed maybe the most effecient way would be to save an object in the database with the long_url and the short_url:randomNumber. My code doesn't throw any errors but when I check my heroku database it has a new entry but only has the _id and __v that mLabs generates itself. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong.

Route File

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var URLShortener = require(process.cwd()+'/public/Modules/urlShortener.module.js');
var ShortURL = require('../models/shortUrl.js');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'FreeCodeCamp Projects' });
});


router.get('/urlShortener', function(req, res){
  res.render('freecodecamp/urlShortener', { title: 'Url Shortener Site'});
});

router.get('/urlShortener/:userUrl', function(req, res){
  if(URLShortener.checkValidUrl(req.params.userUrl))
     {
      var UserUrl = req.params.userUrl;
      var randNbr = URLShortener.assignRanNbr();
      ShortURL.create(URLShortener.createUrlObj(UserUrl, randNbr), function (err, smallUrl) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    else res.json(smallUrl);
    });
   }
else
   {
     res.send('Invalid url');
   }
});

router.get('/:short', function(req, res){
  if(randNbr == req.params.short)
    {
      res.redirect(userUrl);
    }
  else
    {
      res.send('Not the correct shortcut');
    }
 });

module.exports = router;
```

Url Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

var shortUrlSchema = new Schema({
  long_id:String,
  short_id:Number
}, {collection: 'shortUrl'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('shortUrl', shortUrlSchema);
```

urlShortener Module

```
'use strict'

module.exports.checkValidUrl = function(url){
var pattern = new RegExp(/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/);
return pattern.test(url);
}

module.exports.assignRanNbr = function(){
    var randNbr = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    return randNbr;
}

module.exports.createUrlObj = function(url, num){
    var urlObj = {};
    urlObj.original_url = url;
    urlObj.short_url = 'https://rawlejuglal-me-rawlejuglal-1.c9users.io/freecodecamp/'+num;
    return urlObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your createUrlObj method is returning an object with the properties `original_url` and `short_url`, but your shortUrlSchema properties are `long_id` and `short_id`. The property names in your create method need to match your schema. The property value types must also match your schema types (currently `short_url` is a string and `short_id` is a number). I think what you really want is for your createUrlObj method to be

```
module.exports.createUrlObj = function(url, num){
    var urlObj = {};
    urlObj.long_url = url;
    urlObj.short_id = num;
    return urlObj;
}
```

and your schema to be

```
var shortUrlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    long_url: String,
    short_id: Number
}, {collection: 'shortUrl'});
```

Additionally, your `'/:short'` route should have a call to the database since the `randNbr` and `userUrl` variables are not defined in that route.

```
router.get('/:short', function(req, res){
    ShortUrl.findOne({short_id: req.params.short}, function(err, shortUrl){
        if(err) res.send('Invalid Url');
        res.redirect(shortUrl.long_url) 
    })
});
```

Comment: Hey can I ask one more question on this. Everything is working up the the res.redirect. My app.js file has 
app.use('/freeCodeCamp', freeCodeProjects);
with the correct require to contain those routes. so when I was accessing '/:short' it was really freecodecamp/:short. How to I get it to redirect without the freecodecamp/(shortUrl.long_url) because right now the console seems to be putting the freecodecamp/ in front of it

Comment: You need to pass a fully qualified url, which contains the "http://". Try doing res.redirect("http://" + shortUrl.long_url)

Comment: Thanks that was it. You the best!